# Mapping two multi-dimensional arrays by key using php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, mapping

I have 2 multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$array1 = array(
   [0]=>array(
       [items]=>array(
          'item_code'=>'12345',
          'price'=>'145'
       )
   ),
   [1]=>array(
       [items]=>array(
          'item_code'=>'54321',
          'price'=>'260'
       )
   ),
);
$array2 = array(
   [0]=>array(
       [A]=>'12345'
       [B]=>'IMG'
       ),
   ),
   [1]=>array(
       [A]=>'54321'
       [B]=>'PNG'
       ),
   ),
);
```

I am trying to map the two arrays and add a 'type' element, which equals to 'B' column in $array2 into array1, to become a new array:

```
$arrayRes = array(
   [0]=>array(
       [items]=>array(
          'item_code'=>'12345',
          'price'=>'145',
          'type' => 'IMG'
       ),
   ),
   [1]=>array(
       [items]=>array(
          'item_code'=>'54321',
          'price'=>'260',
          'type' => 'PNG'
       ),
   ),
);
```

This is where I am trying:

```
    foreach ($array1 as $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $key1 => $value1) {
              $items = $value1['items'];
              foreach ($items as $item=>$itemValue){
                    foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2){
                       if($itemValue['item_code'] == $value2['A']){
                            $items['type'] = $value2['B'];
                       }
                    }
              }
        }
   }
```

But it keeps returning an error 'Illegal string offset 'items''. Could anyone notice what I did wrong?

Comment: $items = $value1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution :

```
$array1 = array(
   array(
       'items' => array(
          'item_code'=>'12345',
          'price'=>'145'
       ),
   ),
   array(
       'items'=>array(
          'item_code'=>'54321',
          'price'=>'260'
       ),
   ),
);
$array2 = array(
   array(
       'A'=>'12345',
       'B'=>'IMG'
   ),
   array(
       'A'=>'54321',
       'B'=>'PNG'
   ),
);

foreach ($array1 as &$row1) {
    $item = $row1['items'];
    foreach ($array2 as $row2) {
        if ($row2['A'] == $item['item_code']) {
            $item['type'] = $row2['B'];
            break;
        }
    }
    $row1['items'] = $item;
}
```